# Why is minimize_scalar not minimizing correctly?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am a new Python user, so bear with me if this question is obvious.

I am trying to find the value of lmbda that minimizes the following function, given a fixed vector Z and scalar sigma:

```
def sure_sft(z,lmbda, sigma):
     indicator = np.abs(z) <= lmbda;
     minimum = np.minimum(z**2,lmbda**2);
     return -sigma**2*np.sum(indicator) + np.sum(minimum);
```

When I pass in values of lmbda manually, I find that the function produces the correct value of sure_stf. However, when I try to use the following code to find the value of lmbda that minimizes sure_stf:

```
minimize_scalar(lambda lmbda: sure_sft(Z, lmbda, sigma))
```

it gives me an incorrect value for sure_stf (-8.6731 for lmbda = 0.4916). If I pass in 0.4916 manually to sure_sft, I obtain -7.99809 instead. What am I doing incorrectly? I would appreciate any advice!

EDIT: I've pasted my code below. The data is from: https://web.stanford.edu/~chadj/HallJones400.asc

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

# FUNCTIONS

# Calculate orthogonal projection of g onto f  
def proj(f, g):  
    return  ( np.dot(f,g) / np.dot(f,f) ) * f   

def gs(X):

    # Copy of X -- will be used to store orthogonalization
    F = np.copy(X) 

    # Orthogonalize design matrix
    for i in range(1, X.shape[1]):            # Iterate over columns of X
        for j in range(i):                    # Iterate over columns less than current one
            F[:,i] -= proj(F[:,j], X[:,i])    # Subtract projection of x_i onto f_j for all j<i from F_i

    # normalize each column to have unit length
    norm_F=( (F**2).mean(axis=0) ) ** 0.5     # Row vector with sqrt root of average of the squares of each column
    W = F/norm_F                              # Normalize

    return W

# SURE for soft-thresholding    
def sure_sft(z,lmbda, sigma):
    indicator = np.abs(z) <= lmbda
    minimum = np.minimum(z**2,lmbda**2)
    return -sigma**2*np.sum(indicator) + np.sum(minimum)

# Import data.
data_raw =  pd.read_csv("hall_jones1999.csv")

# Drop missing observations.
data = data_raw.dropna(subset=['logYL', 'Latitude'])

Y = data['logYL']
Y = np.array(Y)
N = Y.size

# Create design matrix.
design = np.empty([data['Latitude'].size,15])

design[:,0] = 1
for j in range(1, 15):
    design[:,j] = data['Latitude']**j

K = design.shape[1]

# Use Gramm-Schmidt on design matrix.
W = gs(design)    
Z = np.dot(W.T, Y)/N    

# MLE
mu_mle = np.dot(W, Z)

# Soft-thresholding
# Use MLE residuals to calculate sigma for SURE calculation
sigma = np.sqrt(np.sum((Y - mu_mle)**2)/(N-K))

# Write SURE as a function of lmbda
sure = lambda lmbda: sure_sft(Z, lmbda, sigma)

# Find SURE-minimizing lmbda
lmbda = minimize_scalar(sure).x
min_sure = minimize_scalar(sure).fun #-8.673172212265738

# Compare to manually inputting minimized lambda into sure_sft
# I'm s
act_sure1 = sure_sft(Z, 0.49167598, sigma) #-7.998060514873529
act_sure2 = sure_sft(Z, 0.491675989, sigma) #-8.673172212306728
```

Comment: can you reproduce the error in code which we can run?

Comment: I believe you mean `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar` right?

Comment: I imported at the very top of my code:   
    from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually not doing anything wrong. I just tested out the code and confirmed that `lmbda` has a value of `0.4916759890416824` at the end of the script. You can confirm this for yourself by adding the following lines to the bottom of your script:

```
print(lmbda)
print(sure_sft(Z, lmbda, sigma))
```

when you run your script you should then see:

```
0.4916759890416824
-8.673158394698172
```

The only thing I can figure is that somehow the routine you were using to print out `lmbda` was set up to only print a fixed number of digits of floating point numbers, or somehow the printout was otherwise truncated.